# How do I tell Pine to show me the first high > high[1] after a prior condition has been met?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've recently jumped into Pine having coded for the last few years in Thinkscript but I'm having some issues when trying to isolate the most recent occurrence of a condition then find a different condition only after that occurrence.

The yellow star in the screenshot is the most recent condition.  Logically speaking, if the bar number is higher than the yellow star (10407), I want to find the very first occurrence when a high > high[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BK07.jpg).

In the past, I would just reference the bar number of the most recent condition that say if bar number > the bar number of the most recent condition,  start counting the number of times the high > high[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BK07.jpg).  Then I would reference the first count which would be the bar number I want.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I've tried a number of things like counters, bars since, trying to reference bar numbers, etc but can't figure it out.  Thanks in advance for any help possible!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BK07.jpg)

'''

```
indicator("BarNum Test", shorttitle = 'BN Test', overlay = true, max_bars_back = 1500)

//User Inputs
atrtimeFrame = input.timeframe("D", title="ATR Time Frame")

//HLOC for multi timeframes

[dOpen,dHigh,dLow,dTime] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", [open[0],high[0],low[0],time[0]])
[wOpen,wHigh,wLow,wTime] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"W", [open[0],high[0],low[0],time[0]])
[mOpen,mHigh,mLow,mTime] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"M", [open[0],high[0],low[0],time[0]])
[qOpen,qHigh,qLow,qTime] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"3M", [open[0],high[0],low[0],time[0]])
[yOpen,yHigh,yLow,yTime] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"12M", [open[0],high[0],low[0],time[0]])

//Strat Signals

dTwoDown = dHigh < dHigh[1] and dLow < dLow[1]

// Mag Hit
var dMagHitBearish = 0 
dMagHitBearish := dTwoDown and dLow[2] < dLow[1] and dLow < dLow[2]? 1:0 // low 2 bars ago is less than low of 1 bar ago (validates it wasnt a series of 2 downs and was a tto)

//ATR fo 20 periods

atr20 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, atrtimeFrame, ta.atr(20))

closeOverQhigh = close > qHigh
closeTwiceATR = (atr20 * 2)
closeThriceATR = (atr20 * 3)
    
var c1arg1b = 0
c1arg1b := close > qOpen and close > (qOpen + closeTwiceATR) and dMagHitBearish ? 1 : 0
plotchar( c1arg1b,text = "TTO", location = location.belowbar, color=color.yellow)


var sig = 0
if close > qOpen and close > (qOpen + closeTwiceATR) and dMagHitBearish
    sig :=bar_index
    
label.new(sig, high, text = str.tostring(sig))
//label.new(bar_index, high, text = str.tostring(bar_index))

cond = close > qOpen and close > (qOpen + closeTwiceATR) and dMagHitBearish

var int count = na
if cond
    count := 0
else 
    count +=1
    
since_last = ta.barssince(cond)


cond2 = since_last > 0 and high > high[1]
var int count2 = na
if cond2
    count2 := 0
else 
    count2 +=1
    
since_last2 = ta.barssince(cond2)

label.new(bar_index, high, text = str.tostring(since_last))
plotshape(since_last2 ==0, style=shape.xcross)
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programatically, I am thinking about the following simple general solution for such cases:

```
...
var shouldCheckFirstOccurance = false

if conditionMet
    shouldCheckFirstOccurance := true

if shouldCheckFirstOccurance and occuranceCondition
    shouldCheckFirstOccurance := false // reset condition pass
    // do some logic on the first occurance
```

Comment: Oh!!  This worked perfectly!!!!!!!!!!    below is what I added and its identifying the exact location.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: var shouldCheckFirstOccurance = false

if c1arg1b
    shouldCheckFirstOccurance := true

if shouldCheckFirstOccurance and high > high[1]
    shouldCheckFirstOccurance := false // reset condition pass
    // do some logic on the first occurance
    
plotshape(shouldCheckFirstOccurance[1] == 1 and shouldCheckFirstOccurance==0 , style=shape.circle, color=color.fuchsia)